# How to round up float to integer

Tags: haskell

I have a float `1.23` for instance, if I use `round`, it returns `1`. My desired output is `2`, which is round to the next integer. I can write a function to do it. I just wonder is there any already written function to do it (like `round`). Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `ceiling` function (in `Prelude`):

```
ghci>> ceiling 1.23
2
```

Comment: Which, incidentally is _right after_ `round` in the Prelude.